# File not found in ubuntu

Tags: file, ubuntu, permissions

I am running a shell script that needs access to a file. Initially the file was set to read only, so I changed its permission using the cmd, 'chmod -R 777 filename'. Now when the script is run, I get file not found error even though the file is present in the location with read write access.. Please tell me what is the mistake here.

Comment: Please post the relevant parts of your shell script and the relevant directory layouts (in which directory does the file reside, what are the permissions set on that directory etc.)

Comment: It is a permission problem. But also do ensure that the path is also correct.